# Is it possible to make Next.js Image placeholder without blur?

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, next-images

I'm using Next.js for my projects. Next.js Image component has placeholder and blurDataURL attrs and this combination works very well, but if I want to add my custom placeholder from SVG (SVG->base64) I got blured result.

All my attempts to find information for disabling blur effect was failed... Anybody could help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im kinda amazed this is the only thread I can find talking about this.

Comment: @andrewnosov did you figure this out? It seems like they add a blur ontop of whatever image URL provide, which looks funky if I'm using solid color Base 64's